# Database of monthly climate data 2018 - 2019

Tags: ecology, database

Specifically I'm looking for climate data (average temperature, precipitation) for the summer months of 2018 in Belgium and of 2019 in Japan. Ideally of high spatial resolution, because my areas of study are limited to a transect of a few kilometers in each country.

I've come across other sites such as WorldClim and Prism, but they are always historical data not covering the time intervals I'm looking for, and/or limited to the USA.

I'm trying to examine a possible link between litter decomposition rate and climate at these sites. The decomposition experiment was only conducted over a a timespan of approximately 3 months. Hence I would prefer the climate data of these exact time intervals, and not historical averages or the data collected by nearby weather stations which may record quite different temperatures if they are located in an urban setting.

However, if I need to choose between historical averages that are spatially accurate versus climate data of the exact interval but not spatially accurate (from the nearest weather station), what should I choose for a meaningful comparison between my two sample locations in Belgium and Japan?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Biology. I'll check and see if EarthScience might take it, I don't know what their policies are on requests for data.

Comment: Perhaps try https://opendata.stackexchange.com

Comment: That is not climate data, but weather data. Climate is the average of at least 30 years of weather. Try searches based on weather, and start with the official weather services for both countries. Japan should have an english website, Belgium maybe has one, too.